# Blocking space using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying in CSS to create a div that the goal would be to block the other object from being in this place. I am wondering how could I do such a thing with only CSS.

I have my first div:

```
#Content
{
width:1000px;
height:773px;

margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

position:relative;
}
```

With a second one in the first one:

```
#blocker
{
width:800px;
height:573px;

display:block;
position:absolute;

top:101px;
left:101px;
}
```

The first div will be automatically filled by multiple div like those:

```
.element
{
width:100px;
height:100px;

display:inline-block;

margin:0;

border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:grey;
}
```

The problem is that the "element" is going under the "blocker" while I want it to skip to the next available place for it.

I want something in the middle and I want the element to be display around the blocker.

Hoping it's clear. I've been trying to do it for hour and did not find anything on the web

regards,

Comment: Would you mind posting your HTML code that you have tried as well? Would help a lot :)

Comment: under the blocker is not the next available place?

Comment: Do you care what the HTML looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example 1: Floating elements top, left, right and below a region

This example demonstrates how to float a series of `.element` div's (square blocks) to leave an open rectangular space over which a block element (`#blocker`) can be absolutely positioned.

Consider the following **HTML**. I use two classes to identify the last element in the top row (`.start-skip`) and the last element at the bottom right of the open, rectangular space (`.end-skip`).

```
<div id="Content">
    <div id="blocker"></div>
    <div class="element">1</div>
    <div class="element">2</div>
    <div class="element">3</div>
    <div class="element">4</div>
    <div class="element">5</div>
    <div class="element start-skip">6</div>
    <div class="element">7</div>
    <div class="element">8</div>
    <div class="element">9</div>
    <div class="element">10</div>
    <div class="element">11</div>
    <div class="element">12</div>
    <div class="element">13</div>
    <div class="element end-skip">14</div>
    <div class="element">15</div>
    <div class="element">16</div>
    <div class="element">17</div>
    <div class="element">18</div>
    <div class="element">19</div>
    <div class="element">20</div>
    <div class="element">21</div>
    <div class="element">22</div>
    <div class="element">23</div>
</div>
```

Now, apply the following **CSS**:

```css
#Content {
    width:600px;
    height:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#blocker {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.element {
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:grey;
}
.start-skip ~ .element:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: beige;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
.end-skip ~ .element:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The trick is to use the `~` (adjacent sibling) and  `nth-child()` selectors (part of CSS3) to set the right margin in the rows that will enclose the rectangular space.

The rule with `.start-skip` turns on the wide right margin and the rule with `.end-skip` resets the right margin to zero.

Finally, use absolute position to place the `#blocker` element over the space between the `.start-skip` and `.end-skip` elements.

This approach can be extended to allow two or more elements to the left and right of the rectangular space.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QCYya/

### Example 2: Floating elements right and below a predefined region

In this case, the block element is in the normal content flow and the `.element`'s float to the right and below `#blocker`.

Assuming your HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="Content">
    <div id="blocker"></div>
    <div class="element">1</div>
    <div class="element">2</div>
    <div class="element">3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```css
#Content {
    width:1004px;
    height:773px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    overflow: auto;
}
#blocker {
    width:800px;
    height:573px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}
.element {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:grey;
}
```

You can float all the elements and they will stack in the layout that you are looking for.

Keep in mind that the `.element` blocks are 102px in width and height because of the border
and adjust the `#Content` width accordingly.

Alternatively, you can set the width/height of `.element` to 98px.

Set `overflow: auto` to `#Content` and that will keep the floats from wrapping around any sibling elements before and after `#Content`.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AXfA8/

Comment: Actually, this is part of what I want to accomplish but the reason why I wanted to use position:absolute; is that I want "Element" to be all around, not just at the bottom and at the right.

I want Element at the left, top, right and below. Starting from the top left and continuing to the right... line by line. The line with the blocker will have obviously have on element to the left and one to the right.

Any idea?

Comment: Now that is a different CSS animal all together! It may be possible if the `.elements` are all the same height and width, let me think about it.